# ManagementObjectSearcher adds a new thread in wait, sleep or join state

Tags: .net, multithreading

I am working with WMI to get usb serial number and when i make the following call:-

```
var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");
```

I am in Debug mode and watching under Threads window, I see that a new thread adds right after the execution of this statement which is a worker thread with Location as "[In a sleep, wait or join]".

Could you please tell why it adds the thread and then when I'm out of this block of code, the thread is still in alive and running state( I could see using Thread.CurrentThread)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagementObjectSearcher` is disposable. Try putting it in a using statement:

```
using(var managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"))
{
    //do whatever with managementObjectSearcher 
}
```

or call the Dispose method manually:

```
managementObjectSearcher.Dispose();
```